# Cloud detection based on 4 bands

Tags: gdal, cloud-cover

I have a series of satellite images in 4 bands (red, green, blue and NIR). What is the easiest way to estimate what percentage of each image is covered by clouds? The image is less than 1x1 km with 3-5 m resolution.

As far as I understand, `fmask` does not work here (it requires more bands), but maybe there is some simple heuristic (preferably one that can be calculated just on a pixel-by-pixel basis)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are heuristics for cloud detection but those depend on the exact wavelength of your bands and therefore on the sensor you are using. at 3-5m rgb+nir I would look for similar sensors and available cloud detection algorithms.

RapidEye (5m, rgb+red-edge+nir) comes pretty close and has available heuristics for cloud screening - e.g. from [CONABIO - `rapideye-cloud-detection`](https://github.com/CONABIO/rapideye-cloud-detection).

There are other publications trying to solve the issue of cloud detection with a small amount of bands, however most of them incorporate the short wave infrared bands (e.g. [Hollstein et al.](http://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/8/8/666/htm), [Fisher](http://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/6/1/776/htm)).

The lack of infrared bands makes the cloud screening a challenging endeavour and recent trends are trying to incorporate deep learning to solve the issue, such as [Planets Amazon from Space Kaggle Challenge](https://www.kaggle.com/c/planet-understanding-the-amazon-from-space#description).